# Mouseenter is triggering twice for one enter

Tags: javascript

I want to do something when the div `#demo` is hover, so I use the `mouseenter` event because I don't want it to bubble. There is one nested/child element inside it which is `#test`.

However, the problem is that when I slowly enter the `#demo` from its bottom ( like border ) to the `#test` element, I don't know why it triger the `mouseenter` event twice.

Why does it behave this way? I only want it to trigger the `mouseenter` one time once it is entered.

Here is the code:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('#demo');

main.addEventListener ( 'mouseenter', function (e) {
    this.style.borderStyle = 'none';

    console.log ( 'enter' );
});
```

```css
#demo {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 18px;
}

#test {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this.style.borderColor = 'transparent';` instead.

If use `borderStyle = 'none'` the height of element was changed, so the mouse will leave element for a very short moment, then mouse keep moving and enter second times.

```js
const main1 = document.querySelector('#demo1');
main1.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  this.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  console.log('enter');
});

const main2 = document.querySelector('#demo2');
main2.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  this.style.borderColor = 'transparent';
  console.log('enter');
});
```

```css
#demo1,
#demo2 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: navy;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  padding: 18px;
}

#demo1 {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo1">
  <div id="test1">demo1: border-style</div>
</div>
<div id="demo2">
  <div id="test2">demo2: border-color</div>
</div>
```